# How to store a protocol with associated value in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, socket.io

I have a protocol as follows

```swift
public protocol AdvancedWebSocketRequestProtocol: AnyObject {
    associatedtype ModelType: Codable

    var socketPath: String { get }
    var response: ModelResponse<ModelType>? { get set }
    var responseHandler: ((ModelType?, ServiceError?) -> Void)? { get set }

    func successListener(data: ModelType) -> Void
    func failureListener(error: ServiceError) -> Void
}
```

I then created an object conforming to that protocol

```swift
public class MyStocksWebSocketRequest: AdvancedWebSocketRequestProtocol {
    public typealias ModelType = [InvestmentStockResponse]

    public var socketPath: String = "/socket"
    public var config: [SocketIOClientConfiguration] = []
    public var response: ModelResponse<[InvestmentStockResponse]>?
    public var responseHandler: (([InvestmentStockResponse]?, ServiceError?) -> Void)?

    public func successListener(data: ModelType) { }
    public func failureListener(error: ServiceError) { }
}
```

Then I want to have a `WebSocketManager` class and store an object that conforms to `AdvancedWebSocketRequestProtocol`. Because there are many request classes that conform to the same protocol and I want to be able to pass them all.

Here is what it looks like

```swift
class WebSocketManager {
    private let request: AdvancedWebSocketRequestProtocol
    private let manager: SocketManager
    private let socket: SocketIOClient

    init(request: AdvancedWebSocketRequestProtocol) {
        self.request = request

    }
}
```

I get the following error but I don't think that is the correct solution.

```
Use of protocol 'AdvancedWebSocketRequestProtocol' as a type must be written 'any AdvancedWebSocketRequestProtocol'
```

Is there any way that I can store and pass the objects to `WebSocketManager`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the class generic

```
class WebSocketManager<Request: AdvancedWebSocketRequestProtocol> {
    private let request: Request

    init(request: Request) {
        self.request = request

    }
}
```

Or you could use `any` as suggested in the error message

```
class WebSocketManager {
    private let request: any AdvancedWebSocketRequestProtocol

    init(request: some AdvancedWebSocketRequestProtocol) {
        self.request = request

    }
}
```